# why does all my copied windows with the same exact materials as the original not look the same

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, emission

as the title says, i made a window consisting of two layers, a layer of glass using the glass bsdf with some nodes put into it to get a kind of pane effect, the other layer lies behind and is using a gradient into emission to mimic the look of inside lighting shining through. i know its not perfect. but when i copied the window it didnt keep the glow from the emission. i dont know how to fix this
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The windows are different because you used the object position (presumably of the "first" window) as a texture coordinate. Change the coordinate input to "generated" to get them all. You will have to adjust your mapping slightly (see below):

[image: Generated]